# How to store and access information items in javascript app, JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to store small descriptions and call them into a div at different times using jquery. There are 50 different pieces of data. I thought I'd create a simple json object to store my information. I was wondering how I can access the data with javascript?

I tried this but it doesn't work at all:

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(timeline_info);
var length = myArray.length;
alert(myArray.0[0]);
```

Here is my JSON:

```
var timeline_info = {
    0 : [1972,lorem ipsum blablabla,video address,],
    1 : [1972,lorem ipsum blablabla,video address,],
    2 : [1972,lorem ipsum blablabla,video address,],
    3 : [1972,lorem ipsum blablabla,video address,],
    4 : [1972,lorem ipsum blablabla,video address,],
    5 : [1972,lorem ipsum blablabla,video address,],
    6 : [1972,lorem ipsum blablabla,video address,],
    7 : [1972,lorem ipsum blablabla,video address,],
    8 : [1972,lorem ipsum blablabla,video address,],
    9 : [1972,lorem ipsum blablabla,video address,],
}
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [not JSON](http://jsonlint.com/). Try

```
var timeline_info = [
    {
        "year": 1972,
        "description": "lorem ipsum blablabla",
        "video": "video address"
    },
    {
        "year": 1972,
        "description": "lorem ipsum blablabla",
        "video": "video address"
    }
];
```

and access it with `timeline_info[0].year`.

Comment: Yep - this is a much nicer way to store the data.  With descriptive keys it will improve readability of the code.

Answer (score 3):

- `timeline_info` is not a JSON text, it is a JavaScript object literal.
- `{}` indicates an object, not an array, which is represented by `[]`.
- You should not have a trailing comma at the end of an array or object.
- Strings must be quoted.
- Automatic semi-colon insertion has some gotchas, avoid it.

You have ordered data, use an array literal.

```
var i, timeline_info, length;
timeline_info = [
    [1972,"lorem ipsum blablabla","video address"],
    [1972,"lorem ipsum blablabla","video address"],
    [1972,"lorem ipsum blablabla","video address"],
    [1972,"lorem ipsum blablabla","video address"],
    [1972,"lorem ipsum blablabla","video address"],
    [1972,"lorem ipsum blablabla","video address"],
    [1972,"lorem ipsum blablabla","video address"],
    [1972,"lorem ipsum blablabla","video address"],
    [1972,"lorem ipsum blablabla","video address"],
    [1972,"lorem ipsum blablabla","video address"]
];

length = timeline_info.length;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    console.log(timeline_info[i][0]); // 1972, 10 times.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A  few things are missing here.

1. You should wrap any string literals with quotes.  Like this -
   `[1972,'lorem ipsum blablabla','video address']`
2. You should not have trailing comma characters where you don't need them.  You had an extra comma at the end of each array entry as well as an extra comma after the last element in the object.

---

This would be the correct way to format your object.

```javascript
var timeline_info = {
    0 : [1970,'lorem ipsum blablabla','video address'],
    ...
    8 : [1978,'lorem ipsum blablabla','video address'],
    9 : [1979,'lorem ipsum blablabla','video address']
}
```

Now `timeline_info[0][0]` will return `1970`.